# Is it possible to make an absolute positioned div appear above a fixed element?

Tags: html, css

**What I have**

- A header that is fixed
- Inside the header is a piece of text in the top right
- When I click on the text an absolute positioned div appears underneath it with some 'options'
- In the main content I also have a column on the right that's fixed with a button inside

**The Issue**

- When clicking the text to display the absolute position div 'overlay', the button appears 'on top' of it.

**Question**

- How do I ensure that when I click the text and the additional panel appears, that it appears on top of everything else?

**Some quick code to demonstrate**

If you click on the text in the top right, you'll see the issue.

```js
$('.text').click(function(){
  
  $('.dropdown').toggle();
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  position: fixed;
  background: #ebebeb;
}
.text {
  width: 200px;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}
.text .dropdown {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 65px;
  right: 0;
  background: #888;
  display: none;
}
.text .dropdown ul {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 80px;
}
.content .right-col {
  width: 30%;
  height: 200px;
  float: right;
  background: #ebebeb;
}
.content .actions {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 80px;
  right: 10px;
}
.content .button {
  padding: 20px;
  float: right;
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="text">
      <span> Some text </span>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <ul> 
          <li> Text </li>
          <li> Text </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="right-col">
      <div class="actions">
        <div class="button"> Button </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sounds like a `z-index` issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your `z-index` of your header class lets say 1001 and then set `z-index:1000` action class.

```
.header {
   width: 100%;
   height: 70px;
   position: fixed;
   background: #ebebeb;
   z-index:1001;
}

.content .actions {
   width: 100%;
   position: fixed;
   top: 80px;
   right: 10px;
   z-index:1000; /* less then the header*/
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's it. In my actual code the z-index was on the wrong div. I can't accept this for another 9 minutes. But I will do. Thanks Nasir.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.text').click(function(){
  
  $('.dropdown').toggle();
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  position: fixed;
  background: #ebebeb;
}
.text {
  width: 200px;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}
.text .dropdown {
  z-index:100;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 65px;
  right: 0;
  background: #888;
  display: none;
}
.text .dropdown ul {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 80px;
}
.content .right-col {
  width: 30%;
  height: 200px;
  float: right;
  background: #ebebeb;
}
.content .actions {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 80px;
  right: 10px;
}
.content .button {
  padding: 20px;
  float: right;
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header" style="z-index:199;">
    <div class="text">
      <span> Some text </span>
      <div class="dropdown" >
        <ul> 
          <li> Text </li>
          <li> Text </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="right-col">
      <div class="actions">
        <div class="button"> Button </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="header" style="z-index:199;">
```